# Amazon Seller Central MWS ListOrders GET request fails with "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided."

Tags: signature, amazon-mws

I'm trying to make a GET call to pull orders from Amazon, but I keep getting the same signature error.  I've googled around and I see that a lot of people appear to have this error, but none of their solutions seem to fix my issue.  Any thoughts?

My request code:

```
$MWS_Timestamp=GetUTCFormattedDateTime(Date(Now_()),'UTC',false);   // 2018-10-22T13:51:32Z
$MWS_AccessKey='AKIA****************';
$MWS_ClientSecret='ChOqu*************************';
$MWS_DeveloperID=798*********;
$MWS_SellerID='A3DL**********';
$MWS_MarketPlaceID='ATVP*********';
$MWS_AuthToken='amzn.mws.********-****-****-****-************';

$MWS_Action='ListOrders';
$MWS_RequestString="";
$MWS_RequestString+="AWSAccessKeyId="+UrlEncode($MWS_AccessKey,0);
$MWS_RequestString+="&Action="+UrlEncode("ListOrders",0);
$MWS_RequestString+="&LastUpdatedAfter="+UrlEncode('2018-10-21T00:00:00Z',0);
$MWS_RequestString+="&MarketplaceId.Id.1="+UrlEncode($MWS_MarketPlaceID,0);
$MWS_RequestString+="&SellerId="+UrlEncode($MWS_SellerID,0);
$MWS_RequestString+="&SignatureVersion="+UrlEncode("2",0);
$MWS_RequestString+="&SignatureMethod="+UrlEncode("HmacSHA1",0);
$MWS_RequestString+="&Timestamp="+UrlEncode($MWS_Timestamp,0);
$MWS_RequestString+="&Version=2013-09-01";
$MWS_SignatureString=$MWS_RequestString;

$signature='';
/* Creating signature with CryptoJS
var hmacsha1Data=CryptoJS.HmacSHA1($MWS_SignatureString,$MWS_ClientSecret);  //Also tried $MWS_AccessKey with the same results
var base64EncodeData=CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hmacsha1Data);
$signature=encodeURIComponent(base64EncodeData);
*/
RunScript("<TAG>Scripts/JS-CryptoJS_v3.12</TAG>");

$signature=Replace($signature,"+","%2B");
$signature=Replace($signature,"/","%2F");
$signature=Replace($signature,"=","%3D");

$MWS_Request=$MWS_RequestString+"&Signature="+$signature;

$MWS_URL='https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01?'+$MWS_Request;
```

The Response:

```
<ErrorResponse xmlns="https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>
      The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
    </Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestID>54d6059b-9aa8-4d4f-a0b8-beb663599b25</RequestID>
</ErrorResponse>
```

I'm at a loss here as to which part is wrong.  I double-checked the credentials, but everything looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These parameters must all be appended in lexical order.

Here is one example where that isn't the case.

```
$MWS_RequestString+="&SellerId="+UrlEncode($MWS_SellerID,0);
$MWS_RequestString+="&LastUpdatedAfter="+UrlEncode('2018-10-21T00:00:00Z',0);
```

The order in the actual URL doesn't matter, but if you don't build them in this order then you won't calculate the right signature -- because the service will sort them before calculating the signature it expects you to send.

Also, your signature encoding is wrong.

```
$signature=Replace($signature,"+","%20")
```

There should be only 3 possibilities other than A-Z a-z 0-9:

```
+ becomes %2B
/ becomes %2F
= becomes %3D
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried changing that order, and the encoding..  Still getting the same error. :/

Comment: You also have `SignatureVersion` before `SignatureMethod`.